# use modelformset with queryset and extra information from your model instance

Tags: python, django

I want make a query with filter and then show it in page with the  attribute that I want edit in django,how accomplish it
my model:

```
class DailyReport(models.Model):
    userInfo = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    enterTime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    exitTime = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)  # add null=True in production mode
    overTimeWork = models.FloatField(default=0)
    absenceTime = models.FloatField(default=0)
    restTime = models.FloatField(default=0)
    archive = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rest = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    absence = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class UserInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='نام')
    family = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="نام خانوادگی")
    job = models.CharField(max_length=400, verbose_name="شغل")
    startWorkTime = models.TimeField(verbose_name="ساعت شروع")
    finishWorkTime = models.TimeField(verbose_name="ساعت اتمام")
    allowedWorkTime = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=" ساعت کار")
    allowedabsenceTime = models.FloatField()
    allowedOverTimeWork = models.FloatField()  # better define custom field for getting hour
    fixedSalary = models.FloatField(verbose_name="حقوق ثابت")  # define custom  Field for Salary
    overTimeHourSalary = models.FloatField(
    verbose_name="حقوق ساعت اضافه کار")  # define Field as above for Enter hour salary
    absenceTimeHourSurcharge = models.FloatField(verbose_name="جریمه ساعت غیبت")
    restTimeHourSubtraction = models.FloatField(verbose_name=" کسر ساعت مرخصی")
```

my modelform:

```
class DailyAbsenceRestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DailyReport
        fields = ['absence', 'rest']
```

my modelformset:

```
my_formset = modelformset_factory(DailyReport, form=DailyAbsenceRestForm)
formset=my_formset(queryset=DailyReport.objects.filter(exitTime__day=13).filter(userInfo__name='hassan'))
```

but when I print formset in django template it only show me rest and absence field but I want show me info about DailyReport name and family enterTime exitTime and ....
how accomplish it in django?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `fields = ['absence', 'rest']`.

Comment: it isn't possible do something like that in django?

Comment: I didn't say that.

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many StackOverflow users are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted, so will not learn from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> when I print formset in django template it only show me rest and absence

That behaviour is what you asked for, in the `DailyAbsenceRestForm.Meta.fields` attribute.

If you want to see other fields, you need to allow them to be on the form. The `Meta.fields` specification is used to [restrict what fields will appear](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelforms-overriding-default-fields).

Either remove the `Meta.fields` restriction entirely, or broaden that restriction to include the fields you want to show.

If you want to change the behaviour of fields on the form, use [options on the form fields themselves](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/).

Comment: I only want show info of fileds but I can't edit them and only can edit absence and rest fields